# How to select distinct from multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct

Hi
I'm sure there's query for this kind of operation, but I just can't seem to get it.
I have a table like this:

```
product_id | saved_by | deleted_by | accepted_by | published_by
-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
 1         | user1    |            | user1       |
-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
 2         |          | user2      |             |
-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
 3         | user2    |            |             | user3
-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
 4         |          |            | user1       | user4
-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
```

And I'm trying to create a query that would select all the users in those fields distinctly resulting in something like this:

```
users
------
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is to UNION the columns:

```
  SELECT t.users
  FROM
  (
  SELECT saved_by AS users
  FROM table
  UNION 
  SELECT deleted_by
  FROM table
  UNION 
  SELECT accepted_by
  FROM table
  UNION 
  SELECT published_by
  FROM table
  ) AS t;
```

http://postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-select.html

As a side note if this data was normalized it would be much easier to get the data the way you want.

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT if you do UNION. UNION will already eliminate the duplicates. The proper doc reference you're looking for is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-select.html, the section on "UNION Clause".

Comment: Right, thanks I updated the answer with your info so that it's correct.